# Fix causes sigabort

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I changed it in my code to descriptionLabel, it was not a reserved keyword I think, but nevertheless calling it descriptionLabel is much better.

The compiler is alas not confused, that would have indeed been a logical explanation.

code is now:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
      RhythmCell *cell = (RhythmCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RhythmCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, cell.bounds.size.width-10, cell.bounds.size.height+150)];
      title.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
      title.tag = indexPath.row;
      title.numberOfLines = 2;
      title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

      title.text = cell.descriptionLabel.text;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

      return cell;
 }
```

Comment: what's "title"? Show us teh code!

Comment: I think you should have tried some other string first; i.e., `title.text = @"test";` and see if that would have worked to begin with.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution that removes both the warning and also prevents the exception:   
  
    
`NSString *descriptionText =[(UILabel *) cell.descriptionLabel mutableCopy];`  
    
@Unheilig, the problem is not that it doesn't display text in the label, the issue is (was) that it caused a warning, warnings are bad, so after code functions I try to get them solved. Solving this problem did not seem to work and caused an exception instead. This solution works out well. –  JopieK 5 mins ago

Comment: @JopieK That's what I meant: checking first if the label did set, if not, problem is the cell; if yes, problem is the title. The problem could have been narrowed down. Going back to your solution, why do you think that fixes it.

Comment: @Unheilig, that is indeed a very good question. I think swift is a good solution to such an issues, I have quite some programming experience (masters level), but Objective-C still has a lot of mysteries :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`description` is a method from NSObject protocol (required). This method returns a string that describes the contents of the receiver.

I guess compiler is confused  which `description` you are referring to (since dot syntax can also be used for methods which take no arguments).

Is your UILabel outlet really named "description"? Then I suggest you rename it to something like "descriptionLabel".

Comment: I changed it in my code to descriptionLabel, it was not a reserved keyword I think, but nevertheless calling it descriptionLabel is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call something `description`. That's an existing method on NSObject that returns a string. The crash looks like that's what you're getting back, since you're asking a string for a `text` property.

You probably aren't getting back a cell of the right class, or you haven't implemented description properly, but it's hard to tell from the question.